# Сделать бота Telegram для скачивания видео из TikTok на PHP

Tags: php, telegram-bot, tiktok

Суть простая, пользователь отправляет телеграм боту ссылку на видео из TikTok, дальше как то скачиваем видео и отправляем пользователю уже готовое видео. Кто нибудь сталкивался с таким? Может есть хорошая библиотека для скачивания видео из тиктока на PHP (я гуглил если что). Про то как реализовать отправку видео в Telegram Bot API я знаю. Ребят, самый главный вопрос, как скачать видео из ТикТок посредством PHP!

Answer (score 0):

Будем пользоваться сервисом [tikdown.xyz](https://www.tikdown.xyz/). Отправим POST запрос через CURL с нашей ссылкой на видео из ТикТок. Полная статья [здесь](https://botapi.tech/download-tiktok-video-telegram-bot)

```
$array = array(
  'url'    => "ссылка на видео TikTok" 
);      

$ch = curl_init('https://www.tikdown.xyz/video');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($array));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);    


$dom = new DOMDocument(); // Теперь будем парсить сайт tikdown.xyz
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$tik_link = '';
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
      $array_link = $link->getAttribute('href');
      $tok_link_array = stristr($array_link, '/download'); // ссылка на видео
      $tik_link .= $tok_link_array; // присваиваем ссылку к переменной, чтобы использовать её вне foreach
}

echo $tik_link;
```